# Angular2 Testing - Failed: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'message' since it isn't a known property of

Tags: angular

I have two components which one uses the other.

First one is: `"GamePanelComponent"` **which has html file** that contains:
`"my-game-panel-output"` tag

Second one is:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-game-panel-output',
  templateUrl: 'gamepaneloutput.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ 'gamepaneloutput.component.css' ]
})

export class GamePanelOutputComponent {
    @Input()
    message: string;
}
```

I wrote a test to `GamePanelComponent`:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By }              from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement }    from '@angular/core';

import { GamePanelComponent } from './gamepanel.component';
import { GamePanelOutputComponent } from '../gamepaneloutput/gamepaneloutput.component';

describe('GamePanelComponent (inline template)', () => {

  let comp:    GamePanelComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<GamePanelComponent>;  

  beforeEach( async ( () => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ GamePanelComponent ], // declare the test component
    }).compileComponents()
        .then(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(GamePanelComponent);            
            comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        });
  }));

  it('isValidMove', () => {  
      comp.ngOnInit();      
      let isValid = comp.isValidMove(0,0);
      expect(isValid).toBe(false);
  });

});
```

Unfortunately, test fails with this error:

```
Failed: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'message' since it isn't a known property of 'my-game-panel-output'.
```

As you can see I tried to import "`GamePanelOutputComponent`" and that doesn't help.

I'm really stuck on it.
Can someone assist ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are going to test your `GamePanelComponent` and placed your `<my-game-panel-output>` in the template, your `GamePanelOutputComponent` is a child component of `GamePanelComponent` now. Since your `<my-game-panel-output>` is a custom HTML element angular wouldn't know what to do with it. Therefore you'll have to **declare** it as well.

In order to be able to declare your component you'll have to `import` it first, like you've done already:

```
import { GamePanelOutputComponent } from '../gamepaneloutput/gamepaneloutput.component';
```

Now you have to **declare** your `GamePanelOutputComponent` in the `declarations` of your `TestBed.configureTestingModule()`.

...
`declarations: [ GamePanelComponent, GamePanelOutputComponent ],`
...

---

When your child component is part of a `Module` (eg the `<md-icon>`form the `@angular/material`) you can just `import` the whole module.

```
// Material Design Assets
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
```

To use it you'll have to **import** it your `GamePanelOutputComponent` in the `imports` of your `TestBed.configureTestingModule()`. All material components are *already declared* in the Module so there is no need to declare them again.

...
`imports: [ MaterialModule.forRoot() ],`
...

Comment: can you further explain when do I need to import and when just to add a declaration ?

Comment: Can you tell me why I DID NOT needed to import\declare anything inside GamePanelComponent in order to use GamePanelOutputComponent custom html element, but in order to WRITE A TEST to it I DO need to import GamePanelOutputComponent ?

Comment: Because that is already done in your module that contains those components for your app. For the tests just the tested entity is loaded and not your whole app.

Comment: Whoa! I had the same troubles with nested components driving me insane and it was just the missing declarations! Ouch!